# Mounting 2-bay HDD docking station with 4TB * 2 on FreeBSD 10 or 9.2

Tags: external-hard-drive

I am using an 2-bay HDD docking station.

when I attached 4TB(WD Green) and 128GB(Samsung SSD) in the dock, the two devices are working as well.

but if I attached two same 4TB HDD(WD Green), only one device is working.

So I am wondering if there are some size limitation for USB storage on FreeBSD.

Below, this is dmesg log related it.

```
ugen2.4: <Prolific Technology Inc.> at usbus2
umass0: <Prolific Technology Inc. ATAPI-6 Bridge Controller, class 0/0, rev 2.10/0.00, addr 4> on usbus2
umass0:  SCSI over Bulk-Only; quirks = 0x4001
umass0:8:0:-1: Attached to scbus8
da0 at umass-sim0 bus 0 scbus8 target 0 lun 0
da0: <WDC WD40 EZRX-00SPEB0 80.0> Fixed Direct Access SCSI-0 device 
da0: 40.000MB/s transfers
da0: 3815447MB (7814037168 512 byte sectors: 255H 63S/T 486401C)
da0: quirks=0xa<NO_6_BYTE,4K>
da1 at umass-sim0 bus 0 scbus8 target 0 lun 1
da1: <WDC WD40 EZRX-00SPEB0 80.0> Fixed Direct Access SCSI-0 device 
da1: 40.000MB/s transfers
da1: Attempt to query device size failed: ILLEGAL REQUEST, Invalid command operation
da1: quirks=0xa<NO_6_BYTE,4K>
```

How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no such issues with FreeBSD. Looks like it might be a bad connection between the drive and interposer. Might also be a power issue, have you compared the enclosure's power rating against the drives' specifications?

Comment: but the docking station has the own DC power(12V 5A). So I think it is enough to run two HDDs. is there any ideas you have?

Comment: You think that is enough, or you actually looked at the spec sheet and know that is enough?

Comment: I have seen the spec a little while ago. each HDD requires 4.5W but the current is required with 12V 1.75A. But it transpires that the dock's DC is 12V 3A. But the dock works well on windows.